# Links within a list element are interfering with the hover style

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list of elements, each list element has a frame, background, and an image within them. When you hover over the list element, the entire background changes to orange, and the text changes to white. But when I link the images within the `li` to other pages, everything works, except the text stopped changing to white when I hover. The background still changes to orange either way though, and the text color works perfectly as soon as I take out the `<a href "">` parts.

**HTML**

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-list">
        <b>Title</b>
        Text here should change to white when hovering over entire li element.
        </br>
        <h5 class="discProd">More text</h5>
        <a href="www.youtube.com">
            <img class="iconAlign" src="images/icons/videoIcon.png">
        </a>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```
h6 { 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #2D2D2D; 
    font-weight: 100; 
    line-height: 1.5em; 
}

.discProd { 
    font-size: 10px; 
    color: red; 
} 

#selectable { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    width: 900px; 
}

#selectable li:hover {
    background: orange; 
    color: white; 
}

.ui-state-list {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6 url(../images/Products/productBG5.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    /*searched bg gloss wave */
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555555; 
}

.iconAlign {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 34px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this in your CSS

```
#selectable li:hover span {
    background: orange; 
    color: white; 
}
```

and an added span for the changed text it should all work fine ;)

```
<ol id="selectable">
      <li class="ui-state-list"><b>Title</b>
      <span>Text here should change to white when hovering over entire li element. </span>
      </br>
      <h5 class="discProd">More text</h5>
      <a href="www.youtube.com">
      <img class="iconAlign" src="images/icons/videoIcon.png">
      </a>
      </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

### First, the code you posted actually does exactly what you want it to do.

**But there is a problem.**

You're turning the `<img>` element into a `block` by floating it (default is `inline` for images).  Putting a block element inside of an `inline` element (the `<a>`), is a recipe for disaster (aka rendering outside the bounds of the parent elements as you can see in ***[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dade5/1/)***).

To avoid this, remove the `float: right` on `.iconAlign` and instead, you can make the `<a>` element a block and float it.  You'll need to change the order of your HTML to have your `<a><img></a>` setup come at the beginning of your `<li>` (assuming you're planning to have the element show up on the top right corner as I'm presuming you are).

You also are using an ORDERED list with `<ol>`.  Un-ordered lists are `<ul>` as the letters suggest.  It's also `<br />` (XHTML proper) for a line-break, not `</br>` (although either will result in the same thing in new browsers).  You don't actually need that `</br>` at all since all heading elements (`<h1>, <h2>...<h6>`) default to `block` elements that have a line-break before and after to start with.

## [Here's a little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nPL6L/)

...of what I've covered.  I use an icon from my own server to demonstrate the icon placement.

PS - same protocol goes for `<li>` - not a block element until `display: block` or `float: left/right` is applied.  More information on your goal with this would be very helpful and I could point you in a more obvious direction (such as using a `position: relative/absolute` setup with offsets instead of `float` all together).

PPS - in my demo, Firefox shows my icon smaller than it does in Chrome, just so you are aware that they have different ways of rendering a `.ico` file.

### HTML:

```
<ul id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-list"> 
        <a href="www.youtube.com">
            <img class="iconAlign" src="http://1054.fleeceitout.com/sites/all/themes/jack/favicon.ico" />
        </a>  
        <b>Title</b>
Text here should change to white when hovering over entire li element.
         <h5 class="discProd">More text</h5>
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS:

```
h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #2D2D2D;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.discProd {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: red;
}
#selectable {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 900px;
}
#selectable li:hover {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
}
.ui-state-list {
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background: #e6e6e6 url(../images/Products/productBG5.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    /*searched bg gloss wave */
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555555;
}
a {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 34px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: -.2em;
}
.iconAlign {
    /* no positioning done here since it's an inline element.  position using the block element it's inside of - the <a> */
}
```